# How do I get sudo or admin permissions without using the password

Tags: permissions, sudo

My old computer had linux on my old computer and I had a friend that went into the grub menu and did something and that gave me administration permissions. Lately that friend has not listened to me at all and won't do it again so can someone show me a tutorial on how to do that. It would be GREATLY appreciated. Pls HELP.

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; so any duplicate links may not apply to your *unstated* product & *unstated* release; so adjust accordingly.

Comment: Grub? That suggests your "friend" chose one of the recovery options. Bad idea for regular use.

Answer (score 1):

Open a Terminal window and type the following command:

```
sudo visudo
```

type in your password when prompted and add the following line in the sudoers file

```
$your_user_name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Replace &your_user_name with your username.

<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> -> <kbd>y</kbd> -> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

to save and quit.

Comment: This does not work

Comment: @Pro_Inkling And? Saying "this doesn't work" leads us nowhere if you don't explain what the issue is properly, where you are seeing unexpected behavior, or any errors you are facing.

Comment: This answer is for people who have Sudo already. I don't have Sudo permissions. I want to know how to go into the grub menu and give myself sudo there. I haven't seen anyone who can do it and my friend is not in a good mood with me even though I did nothing to him. SO this answer is not useful.

Comment: My computer is Linux mint 20.3